# C# adding to list of tuples with a function

Tags: c#, tuples

I'm fairly new to C#, just started 2 days ago because I need to create simple project for my Coding classes at University, unfortunately we had 3 days to complete the code so I'm 1 day behind, but it doesn't matter. I created a list of tuples using code fount @ whatacode.wordpress.com.

```
public class TupleList<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>
    : List<Tuple<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>>
{
    public void Add(int IDL, string AlbNmL, string ArtL, int RelDL, int TrAmnL, string LocL, int RatL)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>(ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat));
    }
}
```

I need to create list if it's first addition to tuple so I used if

```
if (currid == 0)
{
    var Albums = new TupleList<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>
    {
        {ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat},
    };
}
```

My ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat are result of readlines etc, doesn't really matter. (or does it??)
I use currid as an indicator whether it's first or not (it start's with 0 and is ++ at the end of the add function.

Now my question is that how can I use the ADD method of my TupleList class in to add them (the ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat that I got from readlines) as a next tuple. I used

```
if(currid > 0)
```

but I don't really know what to put into that if.
Hope my question is understandable in any % and that someone can help me :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your university actually making you use tuples or is there any reason why your not using a class?

Comment: Why not use a List<Tuple<..>>()? You get all the functions you need baked in.

Comment: I don't think your first snippet will compile as is. Have you tried it?

Comment: It does not compile for sure. Also, the author of that blog is, shall we say, "not very experienced". Follow their advice at your own risk.

Comment: I'm free to go with anything, I just couldn't think of any way to use List<Tuple><..>>()

Comment: Hmm. I think it'd be useful if you told us what you're actually trying to achieve here. Whatever it is, the way you're going about it is almost certainly not the right way :)

Comment: changed class to public class TupleList<ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat> : List<Tuple<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>> works now


All I want to achieve is to create a simple database of music albums, I need to be able to sort them, add them, delete them, write and read from file, I also need to be able to play single wav/mp3 file - which is easy, I have to use only 1 file, so I'll play 1 random song of my choice from album (I mean I'll have only single mp3 assigned to every albums as playing doesn't have to be optimal, guy just wants to see we can play a music file in C#)

Comment: @user3658127 OK, but sadly that's not specific enough as a question for stack overflow. The answer Sayse has given is a good starting point - have a fiddle with it, see if you can understand it, and then come back posting specific problems as you encounter them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be *much* better to create an album class and make a list of albums

```
public class Album
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Artist {get; set;}
    public Album(string _name, string _artist)
    {
         Name = _name;
         Artist = _artist;
    }
}


Album example = new Album("a", "good idea");

List<Album> listOfAlbums = new List<Album>();
listOfAlbums.Add(example);
```

Comment: I need to create the whole db in console so I think constructors are not the way to go.

Comment: Fml, I just figured it out how to create that thing, will work hard on it thanks :)

Comment: @user3658127 - As Matt has said, this is entirely a starting point but there are things such as xml serialization that could make populating your list very easy

Comment: is there any way to add iteration to creating new AlbumClass? It needs to work out of console so 1 single name of class will do bad things.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? If your using a console to ask a user for album details then you just take them and pass them to a new instance of an Album? (i.e the 3rd line from bottom in the code example after the equals sign)

Comment: I mean that I have a console user that adds an album through it. If I add Album example = new Album(_name etc); will it do bad things? IE next instance of Album with same name?

Comment: `new` keyword is just that, a new instance, the Album example bit isn't even needed I just put that there for clarity (irony). you could just change the bottom line to `listOfAlbums.Add(new Album("a", "good idea");`

Comment: That's the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can just use a `List<Tuple<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>>`

Second, Your list is only in scope within the curly braces { } of the if (currid == 0) statement.
That means it does not exist outside there, so you need to declare it outside of the if. Then, you can use Add. But also note that Tuple has a Factory method:

```
List<Tuple<<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>> Albums;
if (currid == 0) {
    Albums = new TupleList<int, string, string, int, int, string, int>();
}
Albums.Add(Tuple.Create(ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat));
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case it helps someone, as other replies are not exactly helpful and are nearly 10 years old.

```
//...
var candidateMoves = new List<(Move move, bool isSafe, int pointBenefit)>(); // tuple list definition
candidateMoves.Add(
            (move: m, isSafe: false, pointBenefit: 0)
            );
```

The trick is that you have to specify each "field" of tuple with a colon sign within the parenthesis.